# MySQL query ignores index for a where clause

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I've got a table with a column called "date".

The table looks somthing like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `offers_log_archive` (
                    ...
                    `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
                    ...
                    KEY `date` (`date`)
                ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I perform the following query on this table:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    offers_log_archive as ola
WHERE 
    ola.date >= "2012-12-01" and
    ola.date <= "2012-12-31"
```

Then I did the following:

```
explain (SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    offers_log_archive as ola
WHERE 
    ola.date >= "2012-12-01" and
    ola.date <= "2012-12-31" );
```

The result of this explain is

```
id  select_type  table type possible_keys key  key_len ref  rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE       ola   ALL  date          NULL NULL    NULL 6206460 Using where
```

Why do I get type ALL? From what I know that basically means that the query will inspect every row in the table and ignores the index on date. Although I would expect that mysql would use this.

What happens here and why is the date index ignored?

Comment: What range of dates is in the column?

Comment: From 1 July 2012 until 14 January 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all values in your column are within the range of the query, so not only would the index be next to useless (it would add little value), but it would actually be *much more expensive* to use the index than do a simple table scan.

#### Edit

Try first running [`ANALYZE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html) on the table:

```
ANALYZE TABLE MYTABLE
```

If that doesn't help, try changing the syntax to use `BETWEEN`:

```
WHERE ola.date BETWEEN '2012-12-01' AND '2012-12-31'
```

Comment: Indeed reading the index when you are returning a large percentage of rows will increase that O notation.

Comment: That does not sound right IMHO. The number of rows within this range are 937494 row versus 6206460 rows in total. That would be a fraction of 937494/6206460 = 15 % that are actually touched. For me this is not "Almost all values".

Comment: Additionally I reduced the timeframe from one month to 2 days which reduces the fraction to 61990/6206460 = 0,1%. And still the index is _NOT_ used according to explain. Are you shure you are right?

Comment: Using between uses a range as the index. Query is about 2x faster.